# Xamarin Entry doesnt raise setter of bound item property on last character removal

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a List of Items and an Entry that is bound to the property named "value" of those items.
If I type something in my entry it raises the setter of the property as it's supposed to.
If I remove the characters of the entry the same happens except for the last character if I remove the last character the setter doesnt raise which means my entry is empty but my property is not.

Why? How can I fix that?

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please post some code snippets or a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT for some reason its working now but i dont know why... Also i cant make the problem appear again... But thanks anyway!